# vertical distance between two graphics in sidewaysfigure environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment

I have two `tikz` graphics in a `\sidewaysfigure` environment and i want to separate them with a little vertical spacing. The problem is that the two graphics are directly side by side, only the caption is affected by the `\vspace` statement.

A (not so minimal) working example ([@writelatex](https://www.writelatex.com/350051kyqxcw)):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos]{todonotes}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{trees}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\usepackage{tikz-qtree, tikz-qtree-compat}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaysfigure}[!t]
    \centering
    \tikzstyle{blueBox}=[
        rectangle,
        fill={blue!15},
        draw,
        font=\sffamily
    ]      
    \tikzstyle{grayBox}=[
        rectangle,
        fill=lightgray,
        text=black,
        font=\sffamily,
        draw
    ]
    \tikzstyle{violetBox}=[
        rectangle,
        fill=violet,
        text=white,
        font=\sffamily,
        draw
    ]
    \tikzstyle{greenBox}=[
        rectangle,
        fill=green!50,
        text=black,
        font=\sffamily,
        draw
    ]
    \tikzstyle{derivedFromList}=[
        dashed,
        cyan
    ]
    \resizebox{\textheight}{!}{
            \begin{tikzpicture}[
              level distance=1.1cm,
              level 1/.style={sibling distance=4cm},
              level 2/.style={sibling distance=2cm},
              level 3/.style={sibling distance=2.5cm}
            ]
            \node (root) [violetBox] {anyType}
              [edge from parent fork down]
              child {node[grayBox] {all complex types}
                  edge from parent[loosely dashed, magenta]
              }
              child {node[violetBox] {anySimpleType}
                      child {node[blueBox] {duration}}
                      child {node[blueBox] {dateTime}}
                      child {node[blueBox] {time}}
                      child {node[blueBox] {date}}
                      child {node[blueBox] {gYearMonth}}
                      child {node[blueBox] {gYear}}
                      child {node[blueBox] {gMonthDay}}
                      child {node[blueBox] {gDay}}
                      child {node[blueBox] {gMonth}}
                      child {
                          child [sibling distance = 3cm]{
                              child {node[blueBox] {string}
                                  child {node[greenBox] {normalizedString}}
                                  child {node[greenBox] {token}
                                      child {node[greenBox] {language}}
                                      child {node[greenBox] {Name}
                                          child {node[greenBox] {NCName}
                                              child {node[greenBox] {ID}}
                                              child {node[greenBox] {IDREF}
                                                  child {node[greenBox] {IDREFS}
                                                      edge from parent[derivedFromList]
                                                  }
                                              }
                                              child {node[greenBox] {ENTITY}
                                                  child {node[greenBox] {ENTITIES}
                                                      edge from parent[derivedFromList]
                                                  }
                                              }
                                          }
                                      }
                                      child {node[greenBox] {NMTOKEN}
                                          child  {node [greenBox] {NMTOKENS}
                                              edge from parent[derivedFromList]
                                          }
                                      }
                                  }
                              }
                          }
                          child {node[blueBox] {boolean}}
                          child {node[blueBox] {base64Binary}}
                          child {node[blueBox] {hexBinary}}
                          child {node[blueBox] {float}}
                          child [sibling distance = 3cm] {
                              child {node[blueBox] {decimal}
                                  child [sibling distance = 4cm] {node[greenBox] {integer}
                                      child {node[greenBox] {nonPositiveInteger}
                                          child {node[greenBox] {negativeInteger}}
                                      }
                                      child {node[greenBox] {long}
                                          child {node[greenBox] {int}
                                              child {node[greenBox] {short}
                                                  child {node[greenBox] {byte}}
                                              }
                                          }
                                      }
                                      child {node[greenBox] {nonNegativeInteger}
                                          child {node[greenBox] {unsignedLong}
                                              child {node[greenBox] {unsignedInt}
                                                  child {node[greenBox] {unsignedShort}
                                                      child {node[greenBox] {unsignedByte}}
                                                  }
                                              }
                                          }
                                          child {node[greenBox] {positiveInteger}}
                                      }
                                  }
                              }
                          }
                          child {node[blueBox] {double}}
                          child {node[blueBox] {anyURI}}
                          child {node[blueBox] {QName}}
                          child {node[blueBox] {NOTATION}}
                      }
              };
          \end{tikzpicture}
    }    
    \vspace{2cm}    
    \resizebox{0.5\textheight}{!}{
           \begin{tikzpicture}[framed]
              \node (title) [font=\bfseries] {Legende:};
              \node (base) [violetBox, right = of title] {Basis Typ};
              \node (primitive) [blueBox, right = of base] {Primitiver Typ};
              \node (derived) [greenBox, right = of primitive] {Abgeleiteter Typ};
              \node (complex) [grayBox, right = of derived] {Komplexer Typ};
              \node (d1) [below = of base] {};
              \node (d2) [below = of primitive] {}
                  edge [] node[swap, align=center]{Abgeleitet durch\\Einschränkung} (d1);
              \node (d3) [below = of derived] {};
              \node (d4) [below = of complex] {}
                  edge [dashed, cyan] node[swap, align=center]{von Liste\\abgeleitet} (d3);
              \node (d5) [below = of d2] {};
              \node (d6) [below = of d3] {}
                  edge [loosely dashed, magenta] node[swap, align=center]{Abgeleitet durch\\Erweiterung/Einschränkung} (d5);
          \end{tikzpicture}
    }        
    \caption{vordefinierte XSD Datentypen nach \ldots Kapitel 3}
    \label{fig:xsddatatypes}
\end{sidewaysfigure}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\vspace` does not take effect until LaTeX has reached the end of a line or a paragraph.  If you put a line break after the `\vspace` things should work as you would like.